# Evaluating $\int\frac{A\sin x\,dx}{(\sqrt{1-B\cos^2x}-C\cot x)^3}$

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry

Here's what I think: Let $\cos x=t$ in $$I=\int\frac{A\sin x\,dx}{(\sqrt{1-B\cos^2x}-C\cot x)^3}$$

So,
$$\begin{align*}
I&=-A\int\frac{dt}{(\sqrt{1-Bt^2}-C\frac{t}{\sqrt{1-t^2}})^3}\\
&=-A\int\frac{dt}{(1-Bt^2-2Ct\sqrt{\frac{1-Bt^2}{1-t^2}}+C^2\frac{t^2}{1-t^2})(\sqrt{1-Bt^2}-C\frac{t}{\sqrt{1-t^2}})}
\end{align*}$$

I think, I have made the things more difficult. How can I proceed further? Is there any better substitution for it?

Please help me, Thanks.

Comment: I am ready to bet that $\cot(x)$ is a typo. It should be $\cos(x)$

Comment: Without Claude's modification, even in the comparatively nice cases $B = 0, 1$ the antiderivatives are awfully complicated (albeit elementary).